# Clickpad left click not working on Ubuntu 20.04 when touchpad is not touched

Tags: 20.04, xorg, touchpad, synaptics, libinput

I have a problem with a new Ubuntu 20.04 setup on a new computer (Dell Precision 7550). The clickpad/touchpad looks like the following:

[image: clickpad/touchpad]

The right and middle buttons work without problem. However the click is registered on the left button only when I touch the touchpad at the same time. If I press the left button without touching the touchpad at the same time, the click is not registered by the system and nothing happens.

**Question: how to fix the problem and make the left button of the clickpad work even when the touchpad is not being touched?**

---

Here is the current configuration. The following packages are installed on my computer:

- `libinput-bin 1.15.5-1`
- `libinput10 1.15.5-1`
- `xserver-xorg-input-libinput 0.29.0-1`
- `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 1.9.1-1`

Here is what I get when I print `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL09C3:00 0488:120A Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL09C3:00 0488:120A Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL09C3:00 0488:120A UNKNOWN             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here is the content of the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

```
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
#
# If you want to configure your devices, do not copy this file.
# Instead, use a config snippet that contains something like this:
#
# Section "InputClass"
#   Identifier "something or other"
#   MatchDriver "libinput"
#
#   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
#   ... other Match directives ...
#   Option "someoption" "value"
# EndSection
#
# This applies the option any libinput device also matched by the other
# directives. See the xorg.conf(5) man page for more info on
# matching devices.

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

and the content of `usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Dell Inspiron embedded buttons quirks"
    MatchTag "inspiron_1011|inspiron_1012"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "JumpyCursorThreshold" "90"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Dell Inspiron quirks"
    MatchTag "inspiron_1120"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "JumpyCursorThreshold" "250"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "HP Mininote quirks"
    MatchTag "mininote_1000"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "JumpyCursorThreshold" "20"
EndSection
```

and the content of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Comment: I don't get the question. Did you mean perhaps that the left button only works upon tapping, but not when clicking it? As it stands, it sounds like you're telepathically managing the right and middle buttons, but the pesky left button doesn't want to work like that, only when you're touching it. Other than that, I'd mention that there should be no need in having Xorg configs *(the more so, given people are migrating to Wayland where there is no X server to read X configs)*. You input devices should Just Work™.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Does my edit make the problem clearer?

Comment: Aaah, silly me, I thought the touchpad borders are drawn, but still are part of the touchpad sensor. That is, I thought it's a clickpad. Yeah, thank you for edit, it made it more obvious. Okay, so, I'm surprised synaptics doesn't conflict with libinput. Anyway, it is long obsolete, unmaintained, and should not be used. So let's reduce the problem to just libinput: please remove the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package, your synaptics-related configs, and restart X session.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please check whether BTN_LEFT event is present whenever you're clicking the button without touching the touchpad, in `evemu-record` and `libinput debug-events --verbose` outputs.

Comment: @Hi-Angel `libinput debug-events --verbose` does not register `BTN_LEFT` when the touchpad is not being touched (nothing is written by the verbose mode in the terminal when I press the left button while not touching the touchpad).

Comment: I believe this is the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271281/dell-precision-7550-physical-mouse-buttons-behaving-like-clickpad
The solution on that thread works for me, with some sudden reboot issues.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced a similar issue with my dell precision 7550 with Ubuntu 22.04. My right-click on touchpad wasn't working and my left-click on touchpad only worked whilst I simultaneously had a finger on the touchpad.

The solution was to download a Dell touchpad driver update on the Dell's drivers website for Ubuntu 20.04 (Cirque Touchpad Firmware Update Utility). Now my touchpad works perfectly as it should have.